# Problem Joining FAA raster charts

Tags: raster, transportation

I am new to GIS and I am trying to place the North and South Salt Lake City aeronautical charts in QGIS. The problem I'm having is that there is a black section where the two charts should touch. Am I missing something when I add the raster layers in QGIS? How do I get the maps to join without the black band in the middle? Sectional charts are supposed to have a small overlap between the North and South sides of the map but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. can you tell us which format you are working in? I'm guessing TIFF, but sectional charts are also distributed in PDF. Also, can you tell us where you obtained them, and whether the gap is even across the intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either try to crop your images, or set the no_data value to be transparent.
What is happening is on one or both of your images there is a small edge beyond the map.
That is the band.
you can ...

1. send to back
2. crop your image so it matches exactly to the other sheet.
3. set the image on top to have a transparent color.

Comment: I tried changing the transparency and that did the trick. Thanks!